# Wordpress charset error only happening occasionally

Tags: wordpress

I get the following error on my website, it only happens occasionally.
The host conpany say it is cause dby not using mysql_close in all scripts but I thought PHP did that by default. Either way, I have the standard wordpress installtion so not sure which script could be causing this.

> Warning: mysql_set_charset(): Error executing query in /mysite.com/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 715
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /mysite.com/wp-includes/wp-db.php:715) in /mysite.com/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1121

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Have you tried disabling all of your plugins? It sounds like one of them *is* calling `mysql_close()` when it should not, resulting in the warning from `mysql_set_charset()` because it doesn't have a valid connection anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just disable errors / warnings? Put `error_reporting(0);` in wp config file `wp-config.php` exactly below call of `wp-settings.php` and it won't display any errors / warnings.

```
/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');

error_reporting(0);
```